# type error- call to undefined method in code igniter version3

Tags: codeigniter-3

1.Controller

```
class Client extends CI_Controller {

private $controller = '';
private $data = array();

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Client_model');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->data['is_queue_page'] = true;
    $this->controller = strtolower(__CLASS__);
    $this->base_layout = 'layouts/main_content';
    $this->is_logged();
}

function cliedit( $id ) {
        //$this->data['business'] = $this->treatment_model->get_business();
        $this->data['cliedit'] = $this->Client_model->get_cedit($id);
        $this->data['main_content'] = $this->controller . '/cedit';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main_content', $this->data); }
```

2.model

```
function get_cedit($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->where('client_id', $id);
    return $this->db->get()->r
}
```

3.error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Client_model::get_cedit() in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pms\application\controllers\Client.php on line 113 
>       A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>          Message: Call to undefined method Client_model::get_cedit()  Filename: controllers/Client.php  Line Number: 113  Backtrace:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if all the paranthesis are closed properly, even if it is not closed it might result similar error.